# I have to call Destructor explicitly

Tags: c++, singleton, destructor

```
class TsDatabasePool
{
private:
    TsDatabasePool(int numDBConn, std::string& DBName, std::string& DBType);
            static  TsDatabasePool* objInst_;             
public:
           ~TsDatabasePool();               
    QSqlDatabase* borrowFromPool();      
    void returnToPool(QSqlDatabase*);
static bool createInstance(std::string& DBName, std::string& DBType);
static TsDatabasePool* getInstance();

};
```

My destructor is not called implicitly. Object instance used objInst_ is allocated in private constructor. I dont want to call destructor or call delete objInst_ inside any existing function. Can anyone tell me what should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do here is destroy a singleton object.
It can be done as follows in a Singlethreaded Enviornment:

```
void TsDatabasePool::Destroy()  
{   
    if (objInst_) 
    {        
        delete objInst_;       
        objInst_= 0x0;   
    } 
}
```

Ideally, You can use something like shared_ptr to ensure that the object stays around until no-one needs it any more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::auto_ptr<TsDatabasePool> template instead of raw pointer. std::auto_ptr template will call operator delete on your pointer automatically at application exit.

Comment: There's really no need to call `delete` on anything at application exit.  Application exit will destroy the entire runtime context regardless.

Comment: @aroth, the system will automatically release system-level resources like memory pages and file handles, but there may be important application-level cleanup actions implemented in destructors, such as flushing buffers or gracefully closing network connections.

Answer (score 0):

Until you deallocate `objInst_`, you can not call the destructor for that variable. You need to `delete` it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to free memory and call the destructor for objInst_ is to call

```
delete objInst_;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot (should not) call the destructor unless you *also* delete it. This is part of the design of the C++ language.

Since objInst_ is static you will need to add a "static void shutdown()" method and call it at some point in your code or register it with [atexit](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/atexit.html) function.

**Edit:** realized objInst_ is static.

Comment: objInst_ is static. Calling `delete objInst_` from destructor will cause endless loop if destructor will ever be called.

Comment: *facepalm*. I'm blind. Updated.